# ZSH: Autocomplete second parameter of a function

Tags: list, input, autocomplete, zsh

I'm new to autocompleting in zsh and I tried reading through http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System, but I didn't get it.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I got a (python3-)module asdf.py which is used like

```
python3 /path/to/asdf.py param1 param2,
```

whose second parameter has to be in a certain list (lets say `/tmp/list`, a file containing `['word1', 'word2', ...]`).

How do I get a reference to this list to my .zshrc and how do I tell zsh that only the second parameter should be autocompleted?

Answer (score 0):

From http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html

```
# tell the shell that the function mycompletion can do completion
# when called by the widget name my-completion-widget, and that
# it behaves like the existing widget complete-word
zle -C my-completion-widget .complete-word mycompletion

# define a key that calls the completion widget
bindkey '^x^i' my-completion-widget

# define the function that will be called
mycompletion() {
# add a list of completions
compadd word1 word2 word3
}
```

This is what I have so far. Unfortunaly I have to update the list everytime `/tmp/list` changes.